# Computer failing to boot after installing Ubuntu 12.04.3, "Operating System not found"

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, boot-repair

I've been trying now for 3 weeks to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 on a Sony Vaio laptop. I've learnt a fair bit but am not very knowledgeable compared to a lot of people on here so please bear that in mind. I just finally got a successful Installation Complete window but upon restarting got the same message I've had for the last week, "Operating System not found". I appreciate that there are a few similar questions on here but with so many answers suggested I don't know what to do. I've just run Boot Repair, which failed to make a difference but gave me this link: paste.ubuntu.com/6863876 . Any help is much appreciated; I'm trying hard not to give up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"operating system not found" is a hardware message and it means that the hard disk doesn't have a valid boot sector.
Install your operating system once again and when asked, choose to install the boot loader in the master boot record of the first disk.
If you are in doubt, remove additional hard disks and usb memory sticks before the installation. Install from a CD media.

Comment: What do you mean by " Install your operating system once again and when asked, choose to install the boot loader in the master boot record of the first disk."? I've just installed Ubuntu. I don't have any peripheral devices plugged in and installed from a live DVD. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell since i dont know how you partitioned your disk or how many hard drives you actually have in your laptop. Either way, i think your best shot would be to give it a fresh install. What i mean by that is, if possible, format your drive and reinstall ubuntu once again. My best guess would be that your ubuntu boot-loader failed to install...

Comment: I believe I have one HDD partitioned. I have formatted it using a windows system restore disk (that subsequently failed to install Windows), and have chosen the 'wipe then install' option when installing Ubuntu, which I have now attempted probably at least 6 times. So reinstalling again probably won't do anything. ALSO I've just tried this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition which failed to change anything but gave me the following link: paste.ubuntu.com/6869351